# How to do an API Response using elasticsearch 8.9 in typescript/node?

Tags: javascript, typescript, elasticsearch

I have inherited a project that used to use ES 7.x before that needed upgrading. I've upgraded the package to version 8.9, typescript to 5.2.2 and a bunch of functionality seems to be completely changed. I'm very new to this and really struggling with the official ElasticSearch documentation.

The old code used to work like this:

```
import { ApiResponse } from '@elastic/elasticsearch';

const dataReceived = (result: ApiResponse) => {
  return !!result.body.aggregations.year.buckets.length;
```

If you could point me to some easier to understand documentation with actual examples in code, that will be appreciated greatly!